# Even after setting content type via MimetypesFileTypeMap the downloaded file will not open if it is of any other extension than pdf

Tags: java, mysql, file, jsp, servlets

I am writing a code where i download different files stored in MySQL.
I have set the content type of file by using MimetypesFileTypeMap's method mimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType() it sets the content type of the file right but when the file gets downloaded and i try to open it only pdf file opens rest of the types like png jpeg txt wont open.

Can anyone here help me?

This is my download.jsp page:

```
<%@page import="javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="db.Dbconn"%>
<% 

  try{

       //CONNECTING DATABASE
        Dbconn db = new Dbconn();
        Connection con = db.connect();

        Statement stmt=null;
        ResultSet rst0=null;

        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String sql="Select document,doc_name from `"+request.getParameter("year").toString().toLowerCase()+"itdocs` "
                + "where stud_id='"+request.getParameter("studid")+"' and doc_id='"+request.getParameter("docid").toString()+"';";

        rst0 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rst0.next()){

            MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypesFileTypeMap=new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
            response.setContentType(mimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType(rst0.getString("doc_name").toString()));
            System.out.println("contenttype setting to : "+mimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType(rst0.getString("doc_name").toString()));
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + rst0.getString("doc_name") + "\"");   

            FileInputStream fs=null;
            InputStream is= rst0.getBinaryStream("document");

            File file = new File(rst0.getString("doc_name"));

            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, file);

            fs = new FileInputStream(file);

            int i;   
            while ((i=fs.read()) != -1) {  
              out.write(i);   
            }   
            fs.close(); 
        }

  }catch(Exception eex)
  {
      System.out.println("Exception while downloading file: "+eex.toString());
  }
%>
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the file as? For example if its a jpeg, you open in photos or paint.

Comment: @Maj100 Yes I have tried that but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
 resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
 resp.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

the file name should contain the the file extension. eg.test.txt ot tets.jpg

if you want the file to open in the browser then

```
resp.setContentType(<contentType>);
resp.setHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

you need to use response fileOutputStream

```
try (InputStream inputStream = resultSet.getBinaryStream("FileData");
             OutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream()) {

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while (inputStream.read(data) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(data);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This wont work either! It should work with application/octet-stream but it is not!

Comment: @ManasPatil I guess a servlet would be better for this task than a JSP as there is so much java code.

Comment: The second edit you suggested will also not work. actually i am initiating the download on a button click that's why i haven't used a servlet.

Comment: @ManasPatil on the button click actually an "a" tag you can link to the servlet with the necessary parameters and the servlet could run the code mentioned

Comment: ok i will try the servlet approach. Hope it solves the issue.